# What exactly is this thing at LAX?

Tags: firefighting

I noticed this recently on Google Earth located on the southwest corner of KLAX in Playa Del Ray, CA.

[image]

[image]

Upon examination, I'm guessing the facility is used by firefighting crews for practice putting out jet fuel fires on an aircraft on the ground.  I'd also venture a guess that the smaller fuselages to the right are probably used by the LAPD SWAT team, federal sky marshals or other LE organizations for doing anti-hijacking and other anti-terrorism training.

But what's with all the taxiway paint markings around the red fire aircraft?  Do airport paint crews go out there to test their equipment?

Comment: *"smaller fuselages to the right are probably used by the LAPD SWAT team, federal sky marshals or other LE organizations for doing anti-hijacking and other anti-terrorism training"* I believe they are used more for crew evacuation training.

Comment: *"Do airport paint crews go out there to test their equipment?"* - You know when you change the ink in your printer and print a page to check the ink's flowing properly? Pretty much that

Comment: That's what I was thinking